# The type initializer for 'RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka' threw an exception

Tags: apache-kafka

Getting error "The type initializer for 'RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka' threw an exception." after uploading WCF code on server with framework 4.5.1.

Comment: Does it run locally? How does your directory structure look like on the server? Have you tried the latest version?

Comment: Working now problem came due to framework 4.5.1

Comment: you can always respond to your own question to help people that have this problem in the future?